# Get message in Gmail with Google App Script with specific email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I have a google app script read email to google sheet , and it get all unread inbox email by `var SEARCH_QUERY = "label:inbox is:unread to:me";`

But I just want to get 10 newest message from email `abc1@gmail.com` , how can i achieve that ?

I have tried `var SEARCH_QUERY = "mailfrom:abc1@gmail.com"` but it does not work .

Comment: Please share a sample script for replication and for people in the community to fully visualize your setup. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

> NOTE: Please share a sample script that you're working on in case there's anything else missing on this answer.

*You can try this query:*

`is:unread from:(email_address)`

### Sample Script

```
function myFunction() {
  // Find unread messages from info@send.grammarly.com
  var SEARCH_QUERY = 'is:unread from:(info@send.grammarly.com)';
  var threads = GmailApp.search(SEARCH_QUERY);

  //Only filter the 10 most recent messages
  var last10NewestMessages = threads.filter((_, index) => { return index <= 9 });

  //E.g. log result to return the recent 10 messages' date just to confirm that they're the 10 most recent messages 
  console.log(last10NewestMessages.map(sampleGMessageDate => { return [sampleGMessageDate.getLastMessageDate()] }))
}
```

## Demonstration

[image]

## References:

- [Search operators you can use with
  Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190)

Comment: Tks man ,it works great

Answer (score 0):

#### The Ten Newest

```
function tennewest(){
  const ts = GmailApp.search("label:inbox is:unread to:me");
  let mA = [];
  ts.forEach(t => {
    t.getMessages().forEach(m => mA.push([{from:m.getFrom(),date:m.getDate(),subject:m.getSubject(),body:m.getBody()}]))
  });
  mA.sort((a,b) => {
    let va = new Date(a.date).valueOf();
    let vb = new Date(b.date).valueOf();
    return va - vb;
  })
  return mA.slice(0,10);
}
```

Comment: Tks bro ,i did't try your solution ,but it missed email address .